# Silverlight cross domain error while working in the same domain

Tags: silverlight, ssl, dns

I'm trying to access an .asmx web service with ssl and silverlight client application,
things I have done:
1. I have a crossdomain.xml (only need clientaccesspolicy.xml or crossdomain.xml).
2. I have the  tag in the serviceReferences.ClientConfig file.
3. when I call the webservice with ssl ("https:// . . .") I get the cross domain error
and when I change the access point to be without ssl ("http:// . . .") It works!
4. I browsed the webservice address with and without ssl, boath works.

how can I get a cross domain error while working at the same domain?...

Comment: You only want a `clientaccesspolicy.xml` file as it has more options and was designed for Silverlight (`crossdomain.xml` is an older Flash compatible file). You need to ensure you have allowed https as well as http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have proper entry for the SSL in the `clientaccesspolicy.xaml`. You can check out on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28v=vs.95%29.aspx. However if your web service is hosted in the same web application as the Silverlight application you can pass a relative path to WS in the endpoint configuration of the client (.ClientConfig) and the crossdomain/clientaccesspolicy files won't be required. For example, instead of using address="http://localhost/Services/ExampleService.asmx" use sth like address="../Services/ExampleService.asmx" (depending on the folder in which the XAP file is located).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
        <domain uri="http://*" />
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Like this.
For not obvious reason `<domain uri="http://*" />` actually helps